# Is it possible to migrate a Parallels Desktop Windows VM to Mac OS X BootCamp?

Tags: virtualization, mac-osx-server, bootcamp

I have a Parallels Desktop virtual environment that includes software that cannot be reinstalled elsewhere.  It's native to that VM.  I'm running the environment on my Mac Mini and am seeing huge delays especially with labor intensive tasks.

Is it possible to migrate the virtual environment to Bootcamp?

Comment: Have you tried saving a system image of the Windows VM then restoring it to a partition created by BootCamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. Bootcamp is nothing more than an assistant to perform the somewhat risky tasks required to partition your hard drive and boot a new OS installer in a moreless controlled way.

I'm afraid that, if you are experiencing performance issues, your best chance is to move your VM to a more powerful host and grant higher virtual CPU, memory and IO resources.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! You can! But it's not for the faint of heart. There are more details here that are very easy to follow.

http://www.tylercrumpton.com/?p=90

Here is a summary of what you will need to do:
**Process Outline**

These are the basic steps required to get the job done:

Create the Boot Camp partition and make it bootable.
Copy the source vm’s filesystem to the boot camp partition.
Fix the Boot Camp partition’s mount devices and boot manager.
Fix the Boot Camp partition’s storage controller drivers and registry values.
Profit!

**Prerequisites**

A Mac computer of course.
Parallels Desktop (I’m using Parallels Desktop 7 for this.)
The Windows 7 virtual machine which is to be cloned to the Boot Camp partition. This will be referred to as the “source VM”.
A second Windows 7 virtual machine which you’ll use to manipulate the source VM and the Boot Camp partition. This will be referred to as the “transfer VM”.
A Windows 7 install disk.
Either a Mac OS X install disk or a second Mac that can be connected via a Firewire cable.
A USB flash drive (of any size).